# How to replace a line that starts with a word (and use that old line on the new line)

Tags: sed

I have a file with many lines and I would like to replace specific lines that start with a new line but include the old line in it. See below.

for example, if a line starts with (xyz is different for every line)

```
"#EXT-1,xyz"
```

I would like to have a line like this

```
!group=12, "#EXT-1,xyz", name="#EXT-1,xyz"
```

Is this possible to do with `sed`, and if so, how?

Comment: oh, sorry, will do that

Comment: @bgse It is perfectly On-topic here.

Comment: `I would like to replace specific lines that start with a new line but include the old line in it` So , you mean if line is blank, insert the line before it  in place of blank one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways of formulating it - one would be

```
sed '/^\"#EXT-1,.*\"/ s//!group=12, &, name=&/' file
```

If you want to modify the file in place, then add the `-i` or `--in-place` switch

```
sed -i '/^\"#EXT-1,.*\"/ s//!group=12, &, name=&/' file
```

Comment: it did't write anything to the file, it just listed the lines in the file

Comment: Now I get an message saying "extra characters at the end of d command"

Comment: found the error, my bad.. :-)